# Can I visit the United Kingdom as a tourist while my UK marriage settlement visa is pending (if using keep my passport option)

Tags: visa, uk-visa

I am a US Citizen and travel to the UK often (usually 1 week trips) to see my girlfriend (now Spouse) and visit our clients in London. Since getting married, we want to live in the UK (intention is for me to find a job there once the visa is approved and I have work authorization). Since I usually go to the UK every month with no visa as a visitor, I will need to make a trip or two while the settlement Visa is pending (I plan on keeping my passport while the visa is pending). Will this be allowed?

Comment: Do you have the option of keeping your passport during the visa processing?

Comment: Yes i have the option of keeping my passport

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your passport, if you attempt to visit the most likely outcome is that you just go through an automatic passport reader gate, and never talk to an immigration officer.

However, there is a small potential risk. By applying for a settlement visa you have indicated you are able and willing to move to the UK, increasing the risk of overstay. You can somewhat mitigate that by carrying documents showing your commitment to return to the US after a short visit, such as evidence you are on vacation from a job to which you are expected to return, or that you continue to own or rent your home in the US. Your track record of short visits without overstay would also be in your favor.

The problem is that the downside of being refused entry can be serious, because some countries ask about entry refusal when you apply for visas. It can also be a very unpleasant process, involving detention at the airport until you can be escorted onto a flight back to the US.

You need to decide whether the benefit of a couple of visits during the application process is worth a small risk of a bad outcome.

Comment: Yes that's exactly the outcome i'm trying to grapple with. You've summed it up nicely. I'm obviously not trying to overstay, but there's no guarantee of no problem. Hmm